# Microsoft Bot Framework and Slack - always returning Forbidden

Tags: botframework

I created and registered a Bot on the Microsoft Bot Framework
[image]

I created an app on Slack via the instructions
[image]
[image]

The bot gets added to the channel, but every time I attempt to talk to it, I get a forbidden:

[image]

I assume it is an oauth problem - but what I am I doing wrong?  I confirmed that the clientId and Client secret given to me from Slack are entered correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer
After you publish the bot to Azure the 1st time, you have to go back into Visual Studio and update the appId and appSecret values in the web.config file and then republish.

Comment: I have tried this and it still doesnt work. Did you set the values in the web.config to the client ID and secret from the slack channel